# No module named QSTK in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, qstk

I am trying to import the module

```
import QSTK
import QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil as du
import QSTK.qstkutil.tsutil as tsu
import QSTK.qstkutil.DataAccess as da
```

But I get the Error

```
ImportError: No module named QSTK
```

When I type

```
import sys
sys.path
```

I get:

```
['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\copper-0.0.4-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']
```

And I already have in the path C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\QSTK\qstkutil there the file `qsdateutil.py`

I also already see in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\QSTK\qstkutil` contains a file named `__init__.py`

Anyone can help?

Comment: How did you install it, exactly?

Comment: I tried `conda install` and `pip install`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it doesn't want to be imported at the very top of the package.  Remove that first import of QSTK and see if it works, then.

A glance at some sample code seems to support this.

Comment: I thought that too, but I just tried pip installing it and `import QSTK` worked fine.

Comment: when I try that, I now get the error `ImportError: No module named QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil`

Comment: Do a `pip freeze` and confirm that pip thinks you have this package.  If so, try just an `import QSTK` from the interpreter, as geoelectric did and report back on that.  Are you using a virtual env by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Set the path up within your project, 
this is how i got it to work within my project:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../QSTK-0.2.8')
```